# How can I modify an int pointer without having it as the return value of a function in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I would like to record the number of calls for different recursive functions without having the number of calls as the return value of the function.

For example, I would like to know how many function calls happen for binary search for different keys.

```
int binarySearch (int key, int array[], int lo, int hi, int *recursiveCalls) {
    recursiveCalls++;

    if (lo > hi) return -1;

    else if (lo == hi) {
        if (key == array[lo]) return lo;
        else return -1;
    }

    else {
        int mid = (lo+hi)/2;

        if (key < array[mid])
            return binarySearch(key, array, lo, mid-1, recursiveCalls);
        else if (key > array[mid])
            return binarySearch(key, array, mid+1, hi, recursiveCalls);
        else
            return mid;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int array[10] = {1, 4, 6, 7, 10, 13, 15, 17, 18, 21};
    int *recursiveCalls = 0;
    int index = binarySearch (13, array, 0, 9, recursiveCalls);
    printf ("Number of recursive calls = %d times.\n", *recursiveCalls);
    return 0;
}
```

However, this results in a segmentation fault.

Comment: `recursiveCalls++;` --> `(*recursiveCalls)++;`

Comment: Don't increment the pointer, increment what it points to.

Comment: `binarySearch (13, array, 0, 9, &recursiveCalls);`

Comment: May I please know why this question is "too broad"?

Comment: _May I please know why this question is "too broad"?_.  It is not, at least in my opinion.  But you know the cliches about _opinion_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass pointer in the main which points to 0. Fix it with this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int binarySearch (int key, int array[], int lo, int hi, int *recursiveCalls) {
    (*recursiveCalls)++;
    if (lo > hi) return -1;

    else if (lo == hi) {
        if (key == array[lo]) return lo;

        else return -1;
    }

    else {
        int mid = (lo+hi)/2;

        if (key < array[mid])
            return binarySearch(key, array, lo, mid-1, recursiveCalls);
        else if (key > array[mid])
            return binarySearch(key, array, mid+1, hi, recursiveCalls);
        else
            return mid;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int array[10] = {1, 4, 6, 7, 10, 13, 17, 16, 18, 21};
    int recursiveCalls = 0;
    int index = binarySearch (13, array, 0, 9, &recursiveCalls);
    printf ("Number of recursive calls = %d times.\n", recursiveCalls);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user6005857 see my comment above. Did you add the `&` shown here in the call from `main`? Upvote but the answer should have drawn attention to the faults.

Comment: Have you changed "int * recursiveCalls" declaration to "int recursiveCalls"?

Answer (score 1):

You have been fooled by one of those nasty peculiarities of the C language.

Normally, the values that you can assign to a pointer must be of a pointer type, same as the type of the pointer that you are assigning to.  (Or that can be implicitly converted to it, but let's keep things simple.)  So, for example, you cannot say `char* p = 'a';` because `p` is of type `char*`, while `'a'` is of type `char`.  (One is a pointer, the other one isn't.)

However, C makes an exception: the integer constant zero.  When you assign the integer constant zero to a pointer, C sets the pointer to NULL.

So, your attempt to set the `recursiveCalls` pointer to point to an initial value would have normally been flagged by the compiler as an error, because you are attempting to assign an `int` to an `int*`, but it was not flagged, because C handles the `0` integer literal specially, setting the pointer to NULL.

So, the fix in your situation is to first allocate a variable like this: `int recursiveCallCount; recursiveCallCount = 0;` and then set your pointer to point to it, as follows: `recursiveCalls = &recursiveCallCount;`